# convert Graphical coordinates To Mathematical coordinates in c#

Tags: c#, math, graphical-programming

i want to convert graphical  x,y coordinates x,y to mathematical coordinated

( in this picture you see the Differences between graphical x,y and mathematical x,y

[image: sketch of the situation]

the graphical x  and graphical y obtain by e event

```
         int graphicalx;
        int graphicaly;   
        graphicalx = e.X;
        graphicaly = e.Y;
```

and they showed by two label in the form just should move the mouse on the form

Now the formula for convert graphicalx,y to mathematical x,y is this :

**Graphical x = mathematical x + Alfa**

**Graphical y =** - **mathematical y + Beta**

Now the Alfa and Beta obtain by this :

**you get the your computer resolution :** 
for sample mine is : **1600 * 800**

**alfa = 1600 /2 = 800**

**beta = 800/2 = 450**

At last : 
alfa = 800 
beta = 450

**and now my program don`t works well , where is the problem?**

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int graphicalx;
        int graphicaly;
        int mathematicalx;
        int mathematicaly;


        graphicalx = e.X;
        graphicaly = e.Y;


             if (graphicalx > 0)
        {
            graphicalx = graphicalx * -1; //if graphicalX was positive do it negative

        }
        if (graphicaly > 0)
        {
            graphicaly = graphicaly * -1; //if it graphicalY was positive do it negative

            }

        if (graphicalx < 0)
        {
            graphicalx = graphicalx * +1; // if graphicalX was negative do it positive
        }
        if (graphicaly < 0)
        {
            graphicaly = graphicaly * +1; // if graphicalY was negative do it positive
        }


       mathematicalx = graphicalx + 800; // the formula for obtain the mathematical x 
       mathematicaly = graphicaly * -1 + 450; // the formula for obtain the mathematical y 


        label1.Text = "X = " +mathematicalx.ToString();
        label3.Text = "Y = " + mathematicaly.ToString();

    }
```

**Form 1 Properties :**

**Windows state = Maximized**

**FormBorderStyle = None**

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean the differences are between mathematical and graphical coordinats? Opposed x and y?

Comment: @einord 
see this pic to understand : http://s7.postimg.org/4jejypeor/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have some test cases according to the image and usual conventions, the corners and midpoint should satisfy the correspondence:

```
graphical     |   mathematical
-------------------------------
 (   0,   0)  |    (-800,  450)
 (   0, 900)  |    (-800, -450)
 (1600,   0)  |    ( 800,  450)
 (1600, 900)  |    ( 800, -450)
 ( 800, 450)  |    (   0,    0)
```

Which makes it

```
mathematical.x = graphical.x - 800
mathematical.y = 450 - graphical.y
```

Comment: Wow! thanks @lutzl
it works well but just in 3 parts (TopRight , DownRight,DownLeft) 

but in the TOP LEFT x Should be positive but its negative


you can see the program here : http://www.up2www.com/uploads/139359228131.zip

Comment: Where do you get that requirement for the top-left corner from? In the second and third quadrant of the Cartesian coordinate system, the horizontal x coordinate is negative.

Comment: Oh yes you're right! , i was wrong, in the second Quadrant, x is negative and y is positive

Comment: excuse me another question : How can i  draw the mathematical coordinate axes in the program??

Comment: In plain vanilla winform just by drawing the corresponding lines in the paint event. Perhaps also adding some tick marks,...

Answer (score 2):

Well the first problem that stands out is your reverse equations are not actual a reverse, you need to subtract the values, not add them. Try this:

```
mathematicalx = graphicalx - 800; // the formula for obtain the mathematical x 
mathematicaly = (graphicaly - 450) * -1; // the formula for obtain the mathematical y
```